# Why am i getting linker command failed (undefined reference) error?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I'm trying to use a private function called sortLetters that sorts a string in alphabetical order.

This is the entire code with sortedLetters at the bottom, and I call it in the constructor:

```
#include "scrabbleAssistant.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

ScrabbleAssistant::ScrabbleAssistant(vector<string> words) {
    for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
      this->scrabbleHash.insert(words[i],words[i]);
    }
      //creating the dictionary for anagrams
    for(int i = 0; i < words.size();i++){
      string sortedString = this->sortLetters(words[i]);
      if(!anagramDict.contains(sortedString)){
        vector<string> newAnagramVector;
        newAnagramVector.push_back(words[i]);
        this->anagramDict.insert(sortedString,newAnagramVector);
      }else{
        vector<string> anagramVector = this->anagramDict.get(sortedString);
        anagramVector.push_back(words[i]);
        anagramDict.update(sortedString,anagramVector);
      }
    }

}

ScrabbleAssistant::~ScrabbleAssistant() {
    // TODO: implement destructor
}

bool ScrabbleAssistant::spellCheck(string word) {
    if(this->scrabbleHash.contains(word)){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}

vector<string> ScrabbleAssistant::anagramsOf(string letters) {
   throw runtime_error("Not yet implemented"); 
}

vector<string> ScrabbleAssistant::findWords(string letters) {
    throw runtime_error("Not yet implemented: ScrabbleAssistant::findWords");
}


vector<string> stringPowerSet(string letters){
  vector<string> result;
  //base case: return empty set if letters is empty
  if(letters == ""){
    result.push_back("");
    return result;
  }

  char firstChar = letters[0];
  string sub = letters.substr(1);

  //recursive case: find subset of last n-1 elements in set
  vector<string> smallerResult = stringPowerSet(sub);

  for(int i = 0; i < smallerResult.size(); i++){
      result.push_back(smallerResult[i]); // recursive results
      result.push_back(firstChar+smallerResult[i]); // append first element
  }
  return result;
}
string sortLetters(string s){
  sort(s.begin(), s.end());
  return s;
}
```

I also declared it in the .h file as such:

```
string sortLetters(string s);
```

I'm just wondering why I'm getting this error. 
llllllllllll

Comment: How do you compile? what is your command if you are using command line?

Comment: please place your whole code in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: It's way too much code to put here. I didn't use the sortLetters anywhere else. The error message says: undefined reference to `ScrabbleAssistant::sortLetters(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: also the compiling is done by a command implemented by my university, so I don't think there's any error there

Comment: Where is `sortLetters` defined relative to the definition of `ScrabbleAssistant `?

Comment: *It's way too much code to put here* - Then do what the guidelines require and reduce it to the form of a [mcve]. Asking us to help solve problems with code we cannot see isn't reasonable.

Comment: it's defined after scrabble assistant, but declared in the .h file before scrabble assistant

Comment: I just added all the parts that i edited on the main post ^

Comment: You've declared `sortLetters` as a non-member function.

Comment: but I declared it as a private member of the class

Comment: oh i sthink i get it

Comment: That worked!! thanks!

Comment: and thank everyone else as well for the help :)